# Android: returned value of getX() and getY() when the ImageView is rotated

Tags: android, imageview, location

I have a `FrameLayout` for example like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tools_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgv1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        app:cameraCropOutput="true"
        app:cameraPlaySounds="false" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgv2"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>
```

For `imgv1` user can move, scale and rotate the image. After user moves the `imgv1` with for example dragging it on the screen, if I use:

```
ImageView imgv1;
float xcoordinate, ycoordinate;

xcoordinate = imgv1.getX();
ycoordinate = imgv1.getY();
```

If I have not rotated the `imgv1`, then `getX()` and `getY` will return the position of the top left corner as can be seen here:

### [image]

so in this case the value of `xcoordinate` is `x` and value of `xcoordinate` is `y`.

Now assume that I rotate the `imgv1` and put the top left corner at the same location as before, i.e at (x and y) as shown here:

[image]

Now when I run:

```
xcoordinate = imgv1.getX();       
ycoordinate = imgv1.getY();
```

I don't get `x` and `y` anymore, depending on the angle I get different strange values. What are these returned values and why they are not `x` and `y`?

On some sense, after the rotation, there is no top left corner. So does `getX()` returns the leftmost point which is the x-value for the bottom left of the rotated rectangle and `getY()` returns `y`?

Comment: The question for me here is what do `getX()` and `getY()` return when the ImageView is rotated? Do you have any answer to this question?

Comment: No, I just want to understand what `getX()` and `getY()` return when ImageView is rotated. I think it is a valid question and I like to know what happens, not for my specific application but in general.

Comment: if you're referring by getX() and getY() to the methods inside the onTouchEvent method ,then those two returns the last coordinates of the point where you last touched the screen before you remove your finger. So by that logic if you're rotating your rectangle from the bottom right then the coordinates you're getting at the end are the ones of the bottom right corner not the top left one.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't think `getX()` and `getY()` return the coordinates of the last touch. For example, if I touch the middle of the rectangle and move it so its top right is at `(x,y)`, these two methods return exactly `x` and `y`.

Comment: On my second drawing, can you please tell me what `getX()` and `getY()` are going to return? They do not return `x` and `y`. Can you dhow your answer on a plot or something?

Comment: No what you showed as gray rectangle left top is not what is returned.